# Python - go to two lines above match

Tags: python

In a  text file like this:

First Name last name #
secone name
Address Line 1
Address Line 2
Work Phone: 
Home Phone:
Status:

First Name last name #
....same as above...

I need to match string 'Work Phone:' then go two lines up and insert character '|' in the begining of line. so pseudo code would be:

if "Work Phone:" in line:
   go up two lines:
       write | + line
write rest of the lines.

File is about 10 mb and there are about 1000 paragraphs like this. 
Then i need to write it to another file. So desired result would be:

First Name last name #
secone name
|Address Line 1
Address Line 2
Work Phone: 
Home Phone:
Status:

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution doesn't read whole file into memory

```
p=""
q=""
for line in open("file"):
    line=line.rstrip()
    if "Work Phone" in line:
       p="|"+p
    if p: print p
    p,q=q,line
print p
print q
```

output

```
$ python test.py
First Name last name #
secone name
|Address Line 1
Address Line 2
Work Phone:
Home Phone:
Status:
```

Comment: to write to file:->  `python myscript.py > t`. Or you can do `open()` in the script.  `o=open("out.txt","w"); ... o.write(...+"\n"); ...o.close()`

Comment: i forgot about > t. but it removes all blank lines from the file.  it works nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
lines = text.splitlines()
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if 'Work Phone:' in line:
        lines[i-2] = '|' + lines[i-2]
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work: SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Comment: It works for me.  Have you copied it exactly, because it sounds as if one of the variable names has been replaced by a python keyword.

Comment: @mtpython - you may want to create the lines list from the text variable first...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex

```
(.*\n){2}(Work Phone:)
```

and replace the matches with

```
|\1\2
```

You don't even need Python, you can do such a thing in any modern text editor, like Vim.

Comment: sorry i dont have vim. i did lots of edits with this file with python so i just want to use python.